# matplotlib2tikz date data error

Tags: python, matplotlib2tikz

So I'm trying to convert a plot from python to Tikz with hour data in the x axis.

This is the image in python:

[image]

But when I use the `tikz_save` I got this error:

```
TypeError: a float is required
```

I'm looking and I suppose the error is for the type of data in x. How can i solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult to know exactly what's happening, but from what I can tell this will solve your problem

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
from matplotlib2tikz import save as tikz_save

# input data
t = ['10:00:00', '10:05:00', '10:07:00', '10:27:00']
P = [10, 20, 30, 40]

plt.style.use('ggplot')

fmt = '%H:%M:%S'
tseconds = [datetime.datetime.strptime(k, fmt) for k in t]
dt = [(k - tseconds[0]).seconds for k in tseconds]
dtmax = float(max(dt))
dt = np.array(dt) / dtmax

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(dt, P)
ax.set_xlabel('time')
ax.set_ylabel('Pressure')
fig.canvas.draw()

labels = plt.xticks()
labels = [datetime.timedelta(seconds = label * dtmax) + tseconds[0] for label in labels[0]]
tlabels = [label.strftime(fmt) for label in labels]
ax.set_xticklabels(tlabels)
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)

# export    
tikz_save('test.tex')
```

[image]

I know the `x`-label is off, I will leave that part for you to figure out